# create dictionary from multiple lists, where each list has not the values for one key, but each list has values for all keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have lists like:

```
key1=['A','B','C']
key2=['X','Y','Z']
entry1=['x1','y1','z1']
entry2=['x2','y2','z2']
entry3=['x3','y3','z3']
```

I want my dictionary to have items in the following format:

```
mydict={'A':{'X':'x1','Y':'y1','Z':'z1'},'B':{'X':'x2','Y':'y2','Z':'z2'},'C':{'X':'x3','Y':'y3','Z':'z3'}}
```

Can someone help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier if you start by making the three `entry` lists into a single list.  Then you can `zip` that list with `key1` to get:

```
entries = [entry1, entry2, entry3]
mydict = {
    k1: {k2: e for k2, e in zip(key2, entry)}
    for k1, entry in zip(key1, entries)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is you can use a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
key1=['A','B','C']
key2=['X','Y','Z']
entry1=['x1','y1','z1']
entry2=['x2','y2','z2']
entry3=['x3','y3','z3']

entries = [entry1, entry2, entry3]

my_dict = {k1:{k2:v for k2,v in zip(key2,entry)} for k1,entry in zip(key1,entries)}

print(my_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'A': {'X': 'x1', 'Y': 'y1', 'Z': 'z1'}, 'B': {'X': 'x2', 'Y': 'y2', 'Z': 'z2'}, 'C': {'X': 'x3', 'Y': 'y3', 'Z': 'z3'}}
```